# Python winsound on key press

Tags: python, winapi

I am just learning python and am having difficulty with this piece of code.

```
def down():
    keyPress = win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(0x06)
    print (keyPress)
    if keyPress < 0:
        winsound.Beep(400,200)
    if keyPress > 0:
        winsound.Beep(200,200)
        winsound.Beep(200,200)
```

My goal is to have the program play the first (400,200) sound after I press VK_XBUTTON2. Then after pressing VK_XBUTTON2 again, I want it to play the two (200,200) sounds.

In my program the first beep works, and that makes sense as according to the win32api documentation, pressing the button leads to a result of -32767, however how do I check if the button is pressed again? As if keyPress > 0: does not seem to be working.

Comment: [`GetAsyncKeyState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) reliably reports a single piece of information: The key is currently down (`< 0`), or the key is currently up (`>= 0`).

Answer (score 0):

According to [GetAsyncKeyState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate), 
when the key is down, **GetAsyncKeyState** will return *0b1000000000000001* and *0b1000000000000000* next time.
when the key is **not** down but was pressed after the previous call to **GetAsyncKeyState**, **GetAsyncKeyState** will return *0b0000000000000001*.